# How to search Labels in other language, in Label Search - Dynamics365?

Tags: visual-studio, label, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

In **Dynamics 365**, using *Label Search*, I was able to see only *en-US*@SYS label
[image]

For example, If I want to search in other language: nothing appears 
[image]

There is any wy to chech/view other Labels language?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a bug with label search. I'd submit it to Microsoft.

As a workaround, you can see the label file directly at `C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\ApplicationPlatform\ApplicationPlatform\AxLabelFile\LabelResources\pt-BR\SYS.pt-BR.label.txt`

They're stored in those various sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny for your reply! Good solution.

Comment: @ulisses I made a Tweet at some very smart people https://twitter.com/AlexOnDAX/status/1214752421395615744?s=20 and they've come back with some good info. Palle below provided good info https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642549/1179573 . Also, from the Tweet thread, this may be fixed at some point in a newer version.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason the environments are deployed without the required related XML files for the languages in \AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\ApplicationPlatform\ApplicationPlatform\AxLabelFile.

If you add it manually, search works as expected. The screen shot shows one I made for the Danish SYS label file.

[image]